# Concatenating multiple results of a single XPath query

Tags: php, xpath, xpath-1.0

Given the following HTML table:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="">Example 1</a>
                , 
                <a href="">Example 2</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="">Example 1</a>
                , 
                <a href="">Example 2</a>
                , 
                <a href="">Example 3</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- ... -->
        <!-- Variable amount of rows with variable amount of anchor texts -->
        <!-- ... -->
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

Is it possible to obtain the following results from a **single** XPath query?

1. `Example 1, Example 2`
2. `Example 1, Example 2, Example 3`

---

I tried:

`string(/table/tbody/tr/td//node())`

This obviously doesn't work for the following reason:

> **string(object?)**
>
> converts any of the four XPath data types into a string according to built-in rules. If the value of the argument is a node-set, the function returns the string-value of the first node in document order, ignoring any further nodes.
>
> -- Wikipedia

---

**EDIT**

I make use of PHP's [XPath support](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) which support only v1.0.

The XPath query is meant to be inserted by the user in the config file of a web scraper library I'm building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XPath 2.0 you can do

```
//tr/string-join(.//a/text(), ", ")
```

or

```
//tr/string(normalize-space(td))
```

to [get output](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3Ctable%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctbody%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22%22%3EExample%201%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22%22%3EExample%202%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22%22%3EExample%201%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22%22%3EExample%202%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22%22%3EExample%203%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C!--%20...%20--%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C!--%20Variable%20amount%20of%20rows%20with%20variable%20amount%20of%20anchor%20texts%20--%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C!--%20...%20--%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftbody%3E%0A%20%3C%2Ftable%3E&=%3Ctable%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctbody%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22%22%3EExample%201%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22%22%3EExample%202%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22%22%3EExample%201%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22%22%3EExample%202%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22%22%3EExample%203%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C!--%20...%20--%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C!--%20Variable%20amount%20of%20rows%20with%20variable%20amount%20of%20anchor%20texts%20--%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C!--%20...%20--%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftbody%3E%0A%20%3C%2Ftable%3E&extract=%2F%2Ftr%2Fstring-join(.%2F%2Fa%2Ftext()%2C%20%22%2C%20%22)&=.&input-format=html&printed-node-format=xml&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=xpath2)

```
Example 1, Example 2
Example 1, Example 2, Example 3
```

You can also use programming language libs/features to get output (if you need XPath 1.0 solution). For instance, using Python `lxml.html`

```
for tr in source.xpath('//tr'):
    print(', '.join([a.text for a in tr.xpath('./td/a')]))
```

Comment: Awesome, I confirm that your first XPath 2 solution works as expected. However, I just realize that the language I'm currently on (PHP) does not support XPath 2 and is not likely going to support it anytime soon. Unfortunately the specifications do not allow me to achieve that using the language features as you've suggested... This XPath query is meant to be inserted by the user in a config file of the web scraper I'm building for him… Thanks for your time. I will accept your answer later if no new answer suits better to my edited question.